# python coin flip program that needs a repeat loop 10 times added

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to add a repeat loop that repeats the flip 10 times.

Here is the code:

```
import random

def coinflip()
    return random.randrange(2)

if coinflip == 0:
    print("Heads")
else:
    print("Tails")
```

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) has all the information you require about loops.

Comment: unrelated: you could improve the time performance drastically if you [flip multiple coins at once](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433050/23044)

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean to call the function `coinflip`. Change `if coinflip == 0` to `if coinflip() == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're missing a colon after "def coinflip()"
Second you need to call the coinflip function you defined, right now you're just printing tails every time.
Then put the code in a for loop. You might consider working through some tutorials online or reading through the official documentation. For now, this should be what you're looking for:

```
import random

def coinflip():
    return random.randrange(2)

for i in range(10):
    if coinflip() == 0:
            print("Heads")
    else:
            print("Tails")
```